# Image Processing on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to create a mobile backend with Google App Engine on Google cloud problem.

I want to develop a Java Servlet that accepts image file and performs some image processing effects (tint,blur, ..) on it.

I'm wondering if there are any libraries that can be used for such a scenario.

Can I use something like OpenCV for example, or I will have to implement the effects functionality from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, App Engine has a built-in [Images API for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/) that supports a bunch of different transformations. It may not support everything you're looking for, but it's a low-effort starting point.

Comment: Thanks, I achieved what I want using java.awt.image.BufferedImage APIs